# Dataframe using For Loop in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, dataframe

I need to run the code lines something like this.

```
tweet24042018 = tweets.loc[tweets['date2'] == '24042018'].copy()
tweet23042018 = tweets.loc[tweets['date2'] == '23042018'].copy()
tweet22042018 = tweets.loc[tweets['date2'] == '22042018'].copy()
```

The function created and tried is like this,

```
for key in collect:
    ['tweet'+f'{key}'] = tweets.loc[tweets['date2'] == f'{key}'].copy()
```

But, it gives error like,

```
File "<ipython-input-18-3c946d8cc61a>", line 2
['tweet'+f'{key}'] = tweets.loc[tweets['date2'] == f'{key}'].copy()
^
 SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

help please

Comment: collect is `collect = ['22042018', '23042018', '24042018']`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `locals`

```
variables = locals()
for key in collect:
    variables["tweet{0}".format(key)]= tweets.loc[tweets['date2'] == key]
    print(variables["tweet{0}".format(key)].head())
```

Comment: Thanks, that works but I need to verify its output so how to use this code piece `tweet22042018.head()` in the loop so that all the dataframes can be displayed.

Comment: Please I need to iterate this code `tweet24042018.to_csv("tweet24042018.csv", index = False, header = True, encoding = 'utf-8')` for the values in  `y = ['tweet22042018', 'tweet23042018', 'tweet24042018']`

Comment: do you need the variables, or do you just need to save all of these as csvs?

Comment: I have tried this
`for key in y:
    k = "{0}".format(key)
    z = "{0}".format(key) + ".csv"
    k.to_csv(z, sep=',')`
but it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working, the code is as follows,

```
variables = locals()
 y = []
 for key in collect:
 variables["tweet{0}".format(key)]= tweets.loc[tweets['date2'] == 
 key].copy()

variables["tweet{0}".format(key)].to_csv("tweet{0}".format(key)+'.csv', 
 index = False, header = True, encoding = 'utf-8')
```

If only this code can be simplified.